# Replace innerHTML and get back to the original one keeping the events

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, innerhtml

I have a target div **el** with some components displayed. These components have some events attached (on mouse over, on click). I don't control this code neither those events. They are just there. I'd like to render a widget inside this div. To do so I'm doing something like:

```
var save = el.innerHTML; 
el.innerHTML = "my widget code";
```

When my widget finishes its process I want to get back to the original content so I do:

```
el.innerHTML = save;
```

The components previously saved are correctly replaced but the events attached to them don't work anymore.

I can't hide, show divs. I need to replace the innerHTML to have the exact style and positioning.

What would you do in my case? 
I'm using jQuery if it helps.

Thanks.

Comment: What exactly are you doing to attach the events? `innerHTML` doesn't bind/unbind events - that's why it's nice to use jQuery's `html`, `append`, `empty`, `replaceWith` and whatever else methods - they take care of cleaning up jQuery-bound events. The events that are binded (depending on whether you're using jQuery or not) may not reference an element when you overwrite them with `innerHTML`. What exactly is "my widget code"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you serialize DOM elements back to HTML, all the event handlers and bound data are lost.

If you have DOM, work with it, not with HTML:

```
var save = $(el).children().detach();
$(el).html(widgetHTML);

// later
$(el).empty().append(save);
```

Answer (score 3):

You might find `.detach` useful - http://api.jquery.com/detach/

It does the same as `.remove` but keeps all the associated jquery element data - which will include any event listeners added with jquery, though you will lose any 'regular dom events' attached.

you'd have to re-attach the element with jQuery too:

```
var stored = $(el).detach();

//… wait for something to finish, then reattach

stored.appendTo('#outer');
```

Answer (score 1):

You can delegate the event to your `el` element since it doesn't seem to change - Those newly added elements did not exist at the time of binding

```
$(el).on('click','yourelementtoattachevent',function(){
       // replace click with your event/events
       // your code goes here
});
```

This is assuming you are using jQuery 1.7+, for others use

```
$(selector).live();                // jQuery 1.3+
$(document).delegate(selector, events, handler);  // jQuery 1.4.3+
$(document).on(events, selector, handler);        // jQuery 1.7+
```

Comment: I've just updated the question, I don't have the control on the events.